# working with variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix

Btw, I'm new to MATLAB so my questions may be really easy, but I'd appreciate if you guys can help :)

I have:

```
t = sym('t') and X = [1; sin(2*pi*t); cos(2*pi*t); sin(4*pi*t)];
```

I want to plot t-x graph, such that:

```
x(t) = X(1) + X(2) + X(3) + X(4)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it necessary to use symbolic computations?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate your question a little more,It's not very clear!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, but it is numeric, not symbolic:

```
t = 0:.01:10;
X=[ones(length(t),1) sin(2*pi*t') cos(2*pi*t') sin(4*pi*t')];
plot(t,X(:,1)+X(:,2)+X(:,3)+X(:,4));
```

If you really have to use symbolic toolbox of the matlab then study the function `ezplot()` which is designed for visualizing.